# Incorporating ggsave into R function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this sample data:

```
df <- tibble(
  "PLAYER" = c("Corey Kluber", "CLayton Kershaw", "Max Scherzer", "Chris Sale",
       "Corey Kluber", "Jake Arrieta", "Jose Urena", "Yu Darvish"),
  "YEAR" = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017),
  "WHIP" = c(1.24, 1.50, 1.70, 1.35, 1.42, 1.33, 1.61, 1.10),
  "ERA" =  c(3.27, 4.0, 2.56, 1.45, 3.87, 4.23, 3.92, 2.0)
  )
```

I want the function written below to also save the `ggplot`, using `ggsave` at the end:

```
baseball_stats <- function(player, statistic) {

  # Libraries
  library(tidyverse)
  library(rvest)
  library(ggrepel)

  # Function to set YEAR scale to number of seasons played by pitcher
  f <- function(k) {
    step <- k
    function(y) seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)), by = step)
  }

  # ggplot of player and chosen statistic
  p <- df %>% 
    group_by(PLAYER) %>% 
    filter(PLAYER == player) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes_string("YEAR", statistic), width = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = f(1)) +  # Uses the function to set YEAR breaks
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = f(0.5)) +
    theme_bw() +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(
      title = player,
      subtitle = statistic,
      x = "Year",
      y = statistic,
    caption = "Data from espn.com")

  return(p)

  # ggsave (before or after return()?)
  ggsave(p, file = "/Documents/sports-analysis/MLB/plots-mlb/", player, ".png", 
      device = "png",
      width = 10,
      height = 7)
}
baseball_stats("Corey Kluber", "WHIP)
```

The function, when called, just gives an error when `return(p)` is placed after the `ggsave':

```
Error in to_inches(dim) * scale : non-numeric argument to binary 
operator Called from: plot_dim(c(width, height), scale = scale, units = units, 
limitsize = limitsize)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ggsave` must be before `return(p)`. Nothing after the `return(p)` will run because the function will return immediately upon hitting that function.

The problem is that your call to `ggsave()` is wrong. You need to pass in the file name as a single parameter. You seem to have split it up into different parameters by placing commas between the parts but didn't actually combine those parts into a single file name. Try

```
ggsave(p, file = paste0("/Documents/sports-analysis/MLB/plots-mlb/", player, ".png"), 
  device = "png",
  width = 10,
  height = 7)
```

Comment: I get this error: `Error in grDevices::dev.off() : 
  QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file '/Documents/sports-analysis/MLB/plots-mlb/Corey Kluber.png'`

Comment: The path you showed has a space before the MLB, is that supposed to be there? Also, does the folder currently exist? Or do you need to create that output folder as well?

Comment: The folder exists - I just took off my name from the path, but since we're in the comments: `"/Users/robertpapel/Documents/sports-analysis/MLB/plots-mlb/Corey Kluber.png")` - and that space was from comment formatting, I think

Comment: Well, the error message would suggest there is something wrong with at least part of that file path. Save that path to a variable, say `picpath` and check in R `dir.exists(dirname(picpath))`. Check that you have permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: It returns FALSE. I will recheck. Thank you

Comment: Got it to work. Alas, my quest for clean code doesn't extend to `ggsave`. So it goes.